# Taking the last two rows' minimum value

Tags: pandas

I have this data frame:

```
ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var
 A  16-07-19  3      777      250      810
 A  17-07-19  9      637      121      529
 A  18-07-19  7      878      786      406
 A  19-07-19  4      656      140      204
 A  20-07-19  2      295      272      490
 A  21-07-19  3      778      600      544
 A  22-07-19  6      741      792      907
 B  01-07-19  4      509      690      406
 B  02-07-19  2      732      915      199
 B  03-07-19  2      413      725      414
 B  04-07-19  2      170      702      912
 B  09-08-19  3      851      616      477
 B  10-08-19  9      475      447      555
 B  11-08-19  1      412      403      708
 B  12-08-19  2      299      537      321
 B  13-08-19  4      310      119      125
 C  01-12-18  4      912      755      657
 C  02-12-18  4      586      771      394
 C  04-12-18  9      498      122      193
 C  05-12-18  2      500      528      764
 C  06-12-18  1      982      383      654
 C  07-12-18  1      299      496      488
 C  08-12-18  3      336      691      496
 C  09-12-18  3      206      433      263
 C  10-12-18  2      373      319      111
```

I want to show the minimum value between current row and previous row values, for each column in `123_Var  456_Var  789_Var` set.

That should be applied separately for each ID. (`Groupby`.)

The first row of each ID, will show the current value. (Since there's no "previous" value to compare.)

Expected result:

```
ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Min2  456_Min2  789_Min2
 A  16-07-19  3      777      250      810       777       250       810
 A  17-07-19  9      637      121      529       637       121       529
 A  18-07-19  7      878      786      406       637       121       406
 A  19-07-19  4      656      140      204       656       140       204
 A  20-07-19  2      295      272      490       295       140       204
 A  21-07-19  3      778      600      544       295       272       490
 A  22-07-19  6      741      792      907       741       600       544
 B  01-07-19  4      509      690      406       509       690       406
 B  02-07-19  2      732      915      199       509       690       199
 B  03-07-19  2      413      725      414       413       725       199
 B  04-07-19  2      170      702      912       170       702       414
 B  09-08-19  3      851      616      477       170       616       477
 B  10-08-19  9      475      447      555       475       447       477
 B  11-08-19  1      412      403      708       412       403       555
 B  12-08-19  2      299      537      321       299       403       321
 B  13-08-19  4      310      119      125       299       119       125
 C  01-12-18  4      912      755      657       912       755       657
 C  02-12-18  4      586      771      394       586       755       394
 C  04-12-18  9      498      122      193       498       122       193
 C  05-12-18  2      500      528      764       498       122       193
 C  06-12-18  1      982      383      654       500       383       654
 C  07-12-18  1      299      496      488       299       383       488
 C  08-12-18  3      336      691      496       299       496       488
 C  09-12-18  3      206      433      263       206       433       263
 C  10-12-18  2      373      319      111       206       319       111
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IIUC**, We use [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) to select the previous var for each **ID**, then we can use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)
to leave only the cells where the previous value is lower than the current value and fill with the current value in the rest. We use [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to add `_Min2` and we join with `df` with [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
df_vars = df[['123_Var','456_Var','789_Var']]
df = df.join(df.groupby('ID')['123_Var','456_Var','789_Var']
               .shift()
               .fillna(df_vars)
               .where(lambda x: x.le(df_vars),df_vars)
               .add_suffix('_Min2')
            )
print(df)
```

Output

```
    ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Var_Min2  456_Var_Min2   789_Var_Min2  
0   A  16-07-19  3      777      250      810         777.0         250.0           810.0  
1   A  17-07-19  9      637      121      529         637.0         121.0           529.0  
2   A  18-07-19  7      878      786      406         637.0         121.0           406.0  
3   A  19-07-19  4      656      140      204         656.0         140.0           204.0  
4   A  20-07-19  2      295      272      490         295.0         140.0           204.0  
5   A  21-07-19  3      778      600      544         295.0         272.0           490.0  
6   A  22-07-19  6      741      792      907         741.0         600.0           544.0  
7   B  01-07-19  4      509      690      406         509.0         690.0           406.0  
8   B  02-07-19  2      732      915      199         509.0         690.0           199.0  
9   B  03-07-19  2      413      725      414         413.0         725.0           199.0  
10  B  04-07-19  2      170      702      912         170.0         702.0           414.0  
11  B  09-08-19  3      851      616      477         170.0         616.0           477.0  
12  B  10-08-19  9      475      447      555         475.0         447.0           477.0  
13  B  11-08-19  1      412      403      708         412.0         403.0           555.0  
14  B  12-08-19  2      299      537      321         299.0         403.0           321.0  
15  B  13-08-19  4      310      119      125         299.0         119.0           125.0  
16  C  01-12-18  4      912      755      657         912.0         755.0           657.0  
17  C  02-12-18  4      586      771      394         586.0         755.0           394.0  
18  C  04-12-18  9      498      122      193         498.0         122.0           193.0  
19  C  05-12-18  2      500      528      764         498.0         122.0           193.0  
20  C  06-12-18  1      982      383      654         500.0         383.0           654.0  
21  C  07-12-18  1      299      496      488         299.0         383.0           488.0  
22  C  08-12-18  3      336      691      496         299.0         496.0           488.0  
23  C  09-12-18  3      206      433      263         206.0         433.0           263.0  
24  C  10-12-18  2      373      319      111         206.0         319.0           111.0
```

### **Case 2:** If you want check the `n` previous use `groupby.rolling`

```
df_vars = df[['123_Var','456_Var','789_Var']]
n = 3
df = df.join(df.groupby('ID')['123_Var','456_Var','789_Var']
               .rolling(n,min_periods = 1).min()
               .reset_index(drop=True)
               .add_suffix(f'_Min{n}')

             )
print(df)


   ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Var_Min3  456_Var_Min3  789_Var_Min3 
0   A  16-07-19  3      777      250      810         777.0         250.0         810.0  
1   A  17-07-19  9      637      121      529         637.0         121.0         529.0  
2   A  18-07-19  7      878      786      406         637.0         121.0         406.0  
3   A  19-07-19  4      656      140      204         637.0         121.0         204.0  
4   A  20-07-19  2      295      272      490         295.0         121.0         204.0  
5   A  21-07-19  3      778      600      544         295.0         140.0         204.0  
6   A  22-07-19  6      741      792      907         295.0         140.0         204.0  
7   B  01-07-19  4      509      690      406         509.0         690.0         406.0  
8   B  02-07-19  2      732      915      199         509.0         690.0         199.0  
9   B  03-07-19  2      413      725      414         413.0         690.0         199.0  
10  B  04-07-19  2      170      702      912         170.0         690.0         199.0  
11  B  09-08-19  3      851      616      477         170.0         616.0         199.0  
12  B  10-08-19  9      475      447      555         170.0         447.0         414.0  
13  B  11-08-19  1      412      403      708         170.0         403.0         477.0  
14  B  12-08-19  2      299      537      321         299.0         403.0         321.0  
15  B  13-08-19  4      310      119      125         299.0         119.0         125.0  
16  C  01-12-18  4      912      755      657         912.0         755.0         657.0  
17  C  02-12-18  4      586      771      394         586.0         755.0         394.0  
18  C  04-12-18  9      498      122      193         498.0         122.0         193.0  
19  C  05-12-18  2      500      528      764         498.0         122.0         193.0  
20  C  06-12-18  1      982      383      654         498.0         122.0         193.0  
21  C  07-12-18  1      299      496      488         299.0         122.0         193.0  
22  C  08-12-18  3      336      691      496         299.0         383.0         488.0  
23  C  09-12-18  3      206      433      263         206.0         383.0         263.0  
24  C  10-12-18  2      373      319      111         206.0         319.0         111.0
```

Comment: nice. compact. much simpler than my solution.

Comment: @ansev Cool! And if we want to take the minimum value between current, previous, and two previous ones?

Comment: in this case wee  need use .`rolling` 
why it would not make sense to apply `groupby.shift` n times

Comment: please check case 2

Comment: @ansev, Thank you. I have two questions: (1) Can we use `rolling` in terms of days? (Using `Date` column), and (2) `rolling` ignores `NaN` values?

Comment: Yes, we can also use rolling with date, but we should use `resample` or `reindex`, so that there are no time breaks between rows. In that case, NaN values ​​would be generated. The minimum function ignores them. Why `NaN` is undefined, not 0

Comment: @ansev, May you help me with that one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921931/taking-the-two-minimum-value-of-current-and-previous-day-rolling-min

Answer (score 1):

A quite elegant solution is to apply *rolling(2).min()* to each group,
but to avoid the first row of *NaN* in each group, this first row
should be "replicated" from the source group.

To do your task, start from defining the following function:

```
def fnMin2(grp):
    rv = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([grp.iloc[0, -3:]]),
        grp[['123_Var', '456_Var', '789_Var']].rolling(2).min().iloc[1:]])\
        .astype('int')
    rv.columns = [ it.replace('Var', 'Min2') for it in rv.columns ]
    return grp.join(rv)
```

Then apply it to each group:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(fnMin2)
```

Note that column names assigned to new columns in my solution are
just as you wish, contrary to the solution you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
#this compares the next row to the previous row
ext = df.iloc[:,3:].gt(df.iloc[:,3:].shift(1))
#simply renamed the columns here
ext.columns=['123_min','456_min','789_min']
#join the two dataframes by columns
M = pd.concat([df,ext],axis=1)

#based on the conditions, if it is False, 
#use value from current row,
#else use value from previous row
M['123_min']=np.where(M['123_min']==0,
                      M['123_Var'],
                      M['123_Var'].shift(1)
                     )

M['456_min']=np.where(M['456_min']==0,
                      M['456_Var'],
                      M['456_Var'].shift(1)
                     )

M['789_min']=np.where(M['789_min']==0,
                      M['789_Var'],
                      M['789_Var'].shift(1)
                      )
```