# Taking the minimum value between current and previous day - rolling().min()

Tags: pandas

I have this data frame:

```
ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var
 A  16-07-19  1      NaN      NaN      NaN
 A  17-07-19  7    777.0    250.0    810.0
 A  20-07-19  3      NaN      NaN      NaN
 A  21-07-19  4    295.0    272.0    490.0
 A  22-07-19  8    778.0    600.0    544.0
 A  25-07-19  8      NaN      NaN      NaN
 A  26-07-19  3    435.0    416.0    820.0
 A  27-07-19  8    590.0    455.0    342.0
 A  02-08-19  5      NaN      NaN      NaN
 A  03-08-19  5    717.0    211.0    454.0
 A  05-08-19  1      NaN      NaN      NaN
 A  07-08-19  2      NaN      NaN      NaN
 A  08-08-19  9    105.0    929.0    633.0
 B  09-08-19  6      NaN      NaN      NaN
 B  11-08-19  2      NaN      NaN      NaN
 B  12-08-19  7    413.0    725.0    414.0
 B  13-08-19  7    170.0    702.0    912.0
 B  14-08-19  2    851.0    616.0    477.0
 B  15-08-19  2    475.0    447.0    555.0
 B  17-08-19  3      NaN      NaN      NaN
 B  18-08-19  1    299.0    537.0    321.0
```

I want to show the minimum value between current day and previous day (using `Date` column) values, among `123_Var`, `456_Var`, `789_Var` columns, by `rolling().min()` (or another way).

If there are no values to compare, a `NaN` value will be filled.

This should be applied for each ID separately by `group by`.

Expected result:

```
ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Min_2  456_Min_2  789_Min_2
 A  16-07-19  1      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  17-07-19  7    777.0    250.0    810.0      777.0      250.0      810.0
 A  20-07-19  3      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  21-07-19  4    295.0    272.0    490.0      295.0      272.0      490.0
 A  22-07-19  8    778.0    600.0    544.0      295.0      272.0      490.0
 A  25-07-19  8      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  26-07-19  3    435.0    416.0    820.0      435.0      416.0      820.0
 A  27-07-19  8    590.0    455.0    342.0      435.0      416.0      342.0
 A  02-08-19  5      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  03-08-19  5    717.0    211.0    454.0      717.0      211.0      454.0
 A  05-08-19  1      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  07-08-19  2      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  08-08-19  9    105.0    929.0    633.0      105.0      929.0      633.0
 B  09-08-19  6      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 B  11-08-19  2      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 B  12-08-19  7    413.0    725.0    414.0      413.0      725.0      414.0
 B  13-08-19  7    170.0    702.0    912.0      170.0      702.0      414.0
 B  14-08-19  2    851.0    616.0    477.0      170.0      616.0      477.0
 B  15-08-19  2    475.0    447.0    555.0      475.0      447.0      477.0
 B  17-08-19  3      NaN      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
 B  18-08-19  1    299.0    537.0    321.0      299.0      537.0      321.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further explanation from comment, you may try these steps. Convert `Date` to datetime dtype if it is not in `datetime`. Set `Date` to index. Doing rolling by by `offset` instead of integer.

```
n = 2
cols = ['123_Var', '456_Var', '789_Var']
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True) #if `Date` already datetime dtype, skip this.
df = df.set_index('Date')
df1 = (df.groupby('ID').rolling(window=f'{n}D')[cols].min()
         .reset_index(0,drop=True).add_suffix(f'_min_{n}'))
df_final = df.join(df1)

Out[52]:
           ID  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Var_min_2  456_Var_min_2  \
Date
2019-07-16  A  1      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-07-17  A  7    777.0    250.0    810.0          777.0          250.0
2019-07-20  A  3      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-07-21  A  4    295.0    272.0    490.0          295.0          272.0
2019-07-22  A  8    778.0    600.0    544.0          295.0          272.0
2019-07-25  A  8      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-07-26  A  3    435.0    416.0    820.0          435.0          416.0
2019-07-27  A  8    590.0    455.0    342.0          435.0          416.0
2019-08-02  A  5      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-03  A  5    717.0    211.0    454.0          717.0          211.0
2019-08-05  A  1      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-07  A  2      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-08  A  9    105.0    929.0    633.0          105.0          929.0
2019-08-09  B  6      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-11  B  2      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-12  B  7    413.0    725.0    414.0          413.0          725.0
2019-08-13  B  7    170.0    702.0    912.0          170.0          702.0
2019-08-14  B  2    851.0    616.0    477.0          170.0          616.0
2019-08-15  B  2    475.0    447.0    555.0          475.0          447.0
2019-08-17  B  3      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-18  B  1    299.0    537.0    321.0          299.0          537.0

            789_Var_min_2
Date
2019-07-16            NaN
2019-07-17          810.0
2019-07-20            NaN
2019-07-21          490.0
2019-07-22          490.0
2019-07-25            NaN
2019-07-26          820.0
2019-07-27          342.0
2019-08-02            NaN
2019-08-03          454.0
2019-08-05            NaN
2019-08-07            NaN
2019-08-08          633.0
2019-08-09            NaN
2019-08-11            NaN
2019-08-12          414.0
2019-08-13          414.0
2019-08-14          477.0
2019-08-15          477.0
2019-08-17            NaN
2019-08-18          321.0
```

On `n = 4`

```
In [55]: df_final
Out[55]:
           ID  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Var_min_4  456_Var_min_4  \
Date
2019-07-16  A  1      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-07-17  A  7    777.0    250.0    810.0          777.0          250.0
2019-07-20  A  3      NaN      NaN      NaN          777.0          250.0
2019-07-21  A  4    295.0    272.0    490.0          295.0          272.0
2019-07-22  A  8    778.0    600.0    544.0          295.0          272.0
2019-07-25  A  8      NaN      NaN      NaN          778.0          600.0
2019-07-26  A  3    435.0    416.0    820.0          435.0          416.0
2019-07-27  A  8    590.0    455.0    342.0          435.0          416.0
2019-08-02  A  5      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-03  A  5    717.0    211.0    454.0          717.0          211.0
2019-08-05  A  1      NaN      NaN      NaN          717.0          211.0
2019-08-07  A  2      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-08  A  9    105.0    929.0    633.0          105.0          929.0
2019-08-09  B  6      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-11  B  2      NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN            NaN
2019-08-12  B  7    413.0    725.0    414.0          413.0          725.0
2019-08-13  B  7    170.0    702.0    912.0          170.0          702.0
2019-08-14  B  2    851.0    616.0    477.0          170.0          616.0
2019-08-15  B  2    475.0    447.0    555.0          170.0          447.0
2019-08-17  B  3      NaN      NaN      NaN          475.0          447.0
2019-08-18  B  1    299.0    537.0    321.0          299.0          447.0

            789_Var_min_4
Date
2019-07-16            NaN
2019-07-17          810.0
2019-07-20          810.0
2019-07-21          490.0
2019-07-22          490.0
2019-07-25          544.0
2019-07-26          820.0
2019-07-27          342.0
2019-08-02            NaN
2019-08-03          454.0
2019-08-05          454.0
2019-08-07            NaN
2019-08-08          633.0
2019-08-09            NaN
2019-08-11            NaN
2019-08-12          414.0
2019-08-13          414.0
2019-08-14          414.0
2019-08-15          414.0
2019-08-17          477.0
2019-08-18          321.0
```

---

Note: if you need `Date` back to columns, just `reset_index` on the `df_final`

```
df_final = df_final.reset_index()
```

Comment: If we define `n=4`, row #2 (on `20-07-19`) should show `777.0    250.0    810.0` values.

Comment: @qwerty: you says `If there are no values to compare, a NaN value will be filled`. Row# 2 (`20-07-19`) originally all `NaN`. It means row# 2 has no values,  it should return 'NaN` as your definition.

Comment: I meant when `n=4`, we compare values on window of 4 days, and then there are actual values in row #1 to take into account.

Comment: I try to understand the requirement `If there are no values to compare, a NaN value will be filled`. As in your sample of `n=2`, let's pick windows of row# 1 and 2. There is actual values in row#1, but your desired output shows all `NaN` for row# 2. If follow the explanation in your comment, desired output of row# 2 must be (`777.0    250.0    810.0`).

Comment: I'll explain, `n=2` indicates two days window. There is a difference of three days between row #2 and #1 (see `Date` column). And when we use `n=2`, we can't compare between #2 and #1. When `n=4`, we can.

Comment: @qwerty: after your further explanation, I think I got it. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

To compute minimum for a single column, define the following function:

```
def min2(col):
    return pd.concat([col.dropna(), col.shift()], axis=1,
        join='inner').min(axis=1).reindex(col.index)
```

Then join the original DataFrame with the result of transformation of its
last 3 columns (with this function):

```
df = df.join(df.iloc[:, -3:].transform(min2).rename(
    mapper=lambda col: col.replace('Var', 'Min_2'), axis=1))
```

To get proper column names, there is called *rename* on the transform result,
with a function generating the target column name from the original column
name.

Comment: Please take a look at Andy L.'s answer, and try to fix it considering my comment.